# Saving multiple data dynamic form in Laravel 5.1 and Vue JS

Tags: javascript, forms, laravel-5.1, vue.js

I have to add/post data form. But the form dynamically can increase as user 'click' on a button. I've already browse about it and there some answer i get like using $request->all() to fetch all data from input forms.

And then my problem is, my app using VueJS as front-end. Is there any some configuration on VueJS script to post all data from that dynamic form??

My Blade template that will be increase dynamically:

```
<div id="form-message">
{!! Form::text('rows[0][DestinationNumber]', null, [
    'id' => 'recipient',
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'v-model' => 'newMessage.DestinationNumber'
    ])
!!}
{!! Form::textarea('rows[0][TextDecoded]', null, [
    'rows' => '3',
    'id' => 'recipient',
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'v-model' => 'newMessage.TextDecoded'
    ]) 
!!}
</div>
```

That zero number will increase depends on how much user click add button.
And then here my VueJS script

```
var newSingleMessage = new Vue({
el: '#newsinglemsg',
data: {
    newMessage: {
        DestinationNumber: '',
        TextDecoded: ''
    },
},
methods: {
    onSubmitForm: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var message = this.newMessage;

        this.$http.post('api/outbox', message);
        message = { DestinationNumber: '', TextDecoded: '' };
        this.submitted = true;
    }
}
```

});

On laravel controller, i have simple logic to test result how data passed.

```
$input = $request->all();
$output = dd($input);
return $output;
```

And, I test it using 2 additional form. So, the data should be 3 rows. The result (checked from FireBug) to be like this

```
{"DestinationNumber":"1234567890","TextDecoded":"qwertyuio"}
```

Data passed just one, and then the type is JSON. Even I use return $output->toArray(), type still JSON.

Oh yeah, once more. Idk how to make the zero number increase dynamically using javascript. When testing, i just manual add the form. Here my add click function javascript

```
var i = 0,
clone = $('#form-message').clone(),
recipient = document.getElementById('recipient');
recipient.setAttribute('name', 'rows['+ i +'][DestinationNumber]');
clone.appendTo('.form-message:last');
i++;
```

For second and next rows, name attribute not added on the input elements.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing blade and jquery and vue in a way that is pretty confusing.  Check out this JS fiddle that accomplishes all of this with Vue:

https://jsfiddle.net/cr8vfgrz/10/

You basically have an array of messages that are automatically mapped to inputs using `v-for`.  As those inputs change, your `messages` array changes.  Then when submit is pressed, you just post `this.messages` and the array of messages is sent to server.  Then you can clear the array to reset the form.

Template code:

```
<div id="form-message">
<button class="btn btn-default" @click="addNewMessage">New Message</button>
<template v-for="message in messages">
    <input type="text" v-model="message.DestinationNumber" class="form-control">
    <textarea rows="3" v-model="message.TextDecoded" class="form-control"></textarea>
</template>
<button class="btn btn-success" @click.prevent="submitForm">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Vue code:

```
var newSingleMessage = new Vue({
    el: '#form-message',
    data: {
        messages: [
            {
                DestinationNumber: '',
                TextDecoded: ''
            }
        ],
        submitted:false
    },
    methods: {
        addNewMessage: function(){
            this.messages.push({
                DestinationNumber: '',
                TextDecoded: ''
            });
        },
        submitForm: function(e) {
            console.log(this.messages);
            this.$http.post('api/outbox', {messages:this.messages})
            .then(function(response){
                //handle success
                console.log(response);
            }).error(function(response){
                //handle error
                console.log(response)
            });
            this.messages = [{ DestinationNumber: '', TextDecoded: '' }];
            this.submitted = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Edit:

In the controller you can use `$request->input('messages');` which will be the array of messages.  You can insert multiple new `Outbox` model using:

```
Outbox::insert($request->input('messages'));
```

or

```
foreach($request->input('messages') as $message){
    Outbox::create($message);
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Now how I can save that data with single query or without using loop??

Comment: Would need to see your controller code. Do you have a Model created for these messages and a database table?  Using a loop to save them to the database would be just fine I think

Comment: yes, i have a model. It called "Outbox", column just ID(guarded auto increment), DestinationNumber, TextDecoded and unfortunately I just try to dump it using dd() function :D
Try to use foreach but not sure how to catch value from JSON Object. I mean use this $request->get('this sud be values'). Can you updated your answer for the example?? Noprob if using loop