# aUsing Vue JS to duplicate an input field, incrementing the index

Tags: javascript, clone, vue.js

I need to duplicate a text input field when user clicks a button "add another" and increment the index on the new field. It's similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891882/saving-multiple-data-dynamic-form-in-laravel-5-1-and-vue-js) but that solution didn't increment anything.

What I have duplicates the field and increments the index, but it affects *all* the indexes, not just the newest. (thanks Roy J for the tip)

Here's my template:

```
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="slot in timeslots">
    <div><input type="text" name="performances[@{{ count }}][timestamp]" v-model="slot.timestamp" placeholder="index @{{ count }}"></div>
  </template>
  <span class="add green btn" @click="addAnother"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add another</span>
  <pre>@{{ timeslots | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

Here's what I have in my Vue JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
      timeslots: [
          {
            timestamp: '',
            count: 0
          }
      ],
      count: 0
  },

  methods: {
    addAnother: function(){
      this.timeslots.push({
        timestamp: '',
        count: this.count++
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't you want `this.count++`?

Comment: You mean in the method `addAnother`? Doesn't validate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me if I just qualify `count++` with `this`. I made it pre-increment to avoid making the first elements duplicates.

I've changed the placeholder text to refer to `slot.count` (the current `count`, rather than the parent `count`).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    timeslots: [{
      timestamp: '',
      count: 0
    }],
    count: 0
  },

  methods: {
    addAnother: function() {
      this.timeslots.push({
        timestamp: '',
        count: ++this.count
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.green.btn {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="slot in timeslots">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="performances[@{{ slot.count }}][timestamp]" v-model="slot.timestamp" placeholder="index {{ slot.count }}">
    </div>
  </template>
  <span class="add green btn" @click="addAnother"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add another</span>
  <pre>@{{ timeslots | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: That's close. I guess I wasn't clear enough; I'm trying to increment only the newest field, so that each field's index is sequential.

Comment: @danfo Each field's `count` is sequential. There is also a `count` in the parent, which you were using in the placeholder. I've updated that.

Comment: @RoyJ I see you are using `<input type="text" name="performances[@{{ slot.count }}][timestamp]" v-model="slot.timestamp" placeholder="index {{ slot.count }}">`, however I am inside an MVC app using Razer views so I cannot use the @ symbol. I tried some combinations of v-on: with no success, any ideas for the alternate syntax?

Comment: I don't think there's anything special about the @. You ought to be able to use anything -- it's just constructing a `name` attribute. Also note that this is Vue 1. Interpolation inside attributes isn't supported in Vue 2.